# How to put git log results in an array of arrays? Powershell/ GitBash

Tags: arrays, git, powershell, git-bash, git-log

For a specific branch I would like to;

Run the Git Log command to get the Commit and Filename, this will be executed in Powershell.

I then would like to have For Loop to go through the Commits and have the last Modified filename in a 1 dimensional table, i can use the join cmd in Powershell to join Commit and Filename together.

Example of the Output would be;

### Commit      Filename

14241jdae   FileOne.ps1

24242jdae   FileTwo.ps1

34243jdae   FileThree.ps1

The problem i am having if i run the following

> git log branch1 --pretty=oneline

This displays the result, even if i use a function and call the function, i am struggling how to assign the Git Log output to a 1-Dimensional Array or 2-Dimensional Array table format.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't forget that each commit could modify multiple files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with a `git log <branchName> --name-status --oneline` and then parse that output. The first line is the short commit id followed by short commit message. Following lines start with A|C|D|M|R|T|U|X|B and that will be the change type followed by the filename - shouldn't be hard to parse in any scripting language, take your pick (Python/PERL,....). (See the --diff-format section of http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log for the diff-stat flags).

Comment: Thanks for the input, the git command worked well. 

I did want to know how i can use a foreach loop to go through the "commits" and out put this as a 1-Dimensional array. 

And then i will follow this method of 1-Dimensional Array and another foreach loop to go through filenames to join both to create a 2-Dimensional Array.

Ideally the latest or last modified file must match the commit.

Once this is outputted in a tabular array format i can then work out which file to check.